# VM specific HTTP proxy authentication

Tags: java, http, proxy, ntlm

I assumed that this should be easy to find with Google, but after thorough searching and trying to understand the actual implementation without full success, I thought someone here might perhaps have an idea: Are the implementation specific details on HTTP proxy authentication in Oracle's Java VM (Java 6) documented somewhere?

If not, perhaps someone can shed a little bit light on some of the issues we have encountered:

- The system properties http.proxyUser and http.proxyPassword are obviously not supported anymore. Is that correct?
- Which authentication scheme is used if the proxy offers more than one? It seem to be the first. Actually this shouldn't really matter, but the implementation of the NTLM scheme seem to behave differently, making it important in our case to understand which scheme is actually used.
- If Java decides to authenticate with NTLM, a provided Authenticator is not always used. At least under Windows, an authentication attempt is made with the credentials of the owner of the current process. It is not obvious from the actual implementation, but indicated by other discussions I've found on the net, that the credentials from the Authenticator are used in a second attempt, if the first fails. In our case, the IIS proxy returns a "502 bad gateway" error on the first authentication attempt, so that the Java implementation probably assumes that the problem is not related to the authentication credentials and therefore fails immediately without further authentication attempts. Can someone confirm that this is correct?